# How can i delete the message.channel.send?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
    message.channel.send(`You understand by submitting this strike form you are prepared to be spoken to at any given time per log accepters? Type ***yes*** if you understand.`).then(async (m) => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content === 'yes', {
                max: 1,
                time: 10000,
                errors: ['time'],
            }).then(async (collected) => {
```

So when i send that message with the 'You understand by submitting' that one how can i delete that after like 15 seconds and then how can i delete the awaitMessages one when the user types yes in chat? Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The [`TextChannel#send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method returns a promise with your standard [`<Message>`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object, you can call the [`Message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) function on it like so:

```js
  

    message.channel.send(`You understand by submitting this strike form you are prepared to be spoken to at any given time per log accepters?\n\n Type ***yes*** if you understand.`).then(async (m) => {
    // for the collector it would automatically terminate after 1 response so you may simply continue as it was before
      message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content === 'yes', {
                    max: 1,
                    time: 10000,
                    errors: ['time'],
                }).then(async (collected) => {
      setTimeout( () => m.delete(); collected.first().delete() , 15000) // 15 seconds
        })
```